# How to reuse javascript in a js file using <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I can't get the js file to execute.

I created a js file and added the js file my bundle.

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/cban").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-unobtrusive*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                "~/Scripts/cban.js"
                ));
```

This logic is currently working. The logic will display a new dropdownlist.

```
<ul id="answerEditor" style="list-style-type: none">
    @if (Model.Answers != null)
    {
        foreach (AnswerVM answer in Model.Answers)
        {
            answer.AllAnswers = Model.AllAnswers;
            Html.RenderPartial("_AnswerEntryEditor", answer);
        }
    }
</ul>
```

This link will allow the user to click calling the javascript.

```
<a id="addAnother" href="#">Add another</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
    $("#addAnother").click(function () {
        $.get('/Question/AnswerEntryRow', function (template) {
            $("#answerEditor").append(template);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I changed the code to work like this on the view.

```
<a href="#" method="get" action="@Url.Action("QuestionEntryRow", "QuestionGroup")"
   data-cban-target="questionEditor" data-cban-ajax="true">Add another</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/cban.js"></script>
```

The js file looks like this.

```
$(function() {
  var insertRow = function () {
      var $a = $(this);
      var options = {
          url: $a.attr("action"),
          type: $a.attr("method")
      };

      $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
          var $target = $($a.attr("data-cban-target"));
          $target.append(data);
      });
      return false
  };

  $(document).ready()
  {
    $("a[data-cban-ajax='true']").click(insertRow);
  }
});
```

When I click the link the js file is not executing.

Comment: Remove `$(document).ready(){}` that's redundant because you wrap everything with `$(function() { })`. Now remove everything from `insertRow = function() { return false; }`. Even better make it `insertRow = function(event) { event.preventDefault(); console.log("click"); }` -- then see if the click handler works. Make sure that works then you can fix and insert your AJAX call.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I made the following changes.  The js file looks like this now.     $(function() {

  insertRow = function (event) {
      event.preventDefault(); console.log("click");
  }

  $("a[data-cban-ajax='true']").click(insertRow);

});    When I click the link.  Nothing is firing. I also tried changing the href to  href="javascript:void(0);"

Comment: You'll need to label your code snippets with their file names in this question so it's clearer about what you've got set up. Make sure the console is clear of errors and that you have jquery loaded before your _cban.js_ script. If you're loading the script in the bundler make sure you've recompiled and properly reference the bundle in your view. Check that no other handler can intercept your clicks -- remove everything but jquery and cban.js to be sure. Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UJJ3eY) example.

Answer (score 0):

I found several issue with my code.

1) I had to move my custom bundle to the bottom my layout.cshtml

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/cban")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

2) Then I had to change my view href attribute data attribute from "questionEditor" to "#questionEditor" for data-cban-target.

```
<a href="#" method="get" action="@Url.Action("QuestionEntryRow", "QuestionGroup")"
   data-cban-target="#questionEditor" data-cban-ajax="true">Add another</a>
```

3) And then I changed my actual target from data-cban-target="questionEditor" to id="questionEditor"

```
<ul id="questionEditor" style="list-style-type: none">
    @if (Model.Questions != null)
    {
        foreach (QuestionVM question in Model.Questions)
        {

            Html.RenderPartial("_QuestionEntryEditor", question);
        }
    }
</ul>
```

4) I also had to change the @section scripts at the bottom of my view.

Changed from this :

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

To This

```
@section Scripts {

}
```

I seem to also have a problem using chrome.  When I changed over to IE I was able to debug my js file.  I could not understand why that was happening.

Anyway I am working now.  Thanks for the help.